# Laravel order by column and relationship column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query which has needs to order by additional data on relationship columns. This is my most recent attempt:

```
$odds = Odd::with([
        'box', 'set'
    ])->get()->sortBy(function($query) {
        return $query->box->position;
    })->sortBy('created_at');
```

The current database tables are like so:

```
Odds
id.    box_id.   created_at
1      1         2021-04-02 17:15:04
2      2         2021-04-02 17:15:04
3      3         2021-04-02 17:15:04
4      4         2021-04-02 17:20:05

Box
id     set_id    position
1      1         3
2      1         1
3      1         5
4      2         2
```

The query above is able to sort on odds.created_at, but will not sort on the box.position. The result needs to be in date order then with in date group needs to be ordered by position, like so:

```
id.    box_id.   created_at            set_id    position
2      2         2021-04-02 17:15:04   1         1
1      1         2021-04-02 17:15:04   1         3
3      3         2021-04-02 17:15:04   1         5
4      4         2021-04-02 17:20:05   2         2
```

I have also tried these methods:

```
$odds = Odd::with([
        'box', 'set'
    ])->get()->sortBy('created_at')->sortBy('box.position');

$odds = Odd::with([
        'box' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('position');
            },
        'set'
    ])->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Comment: it seems impossible to me for current structure, the second order/sort will always replace the first order/sort, don't you think?

Comment: It appears that with some of the queries that is the case, but I know I can do this with MYSQL raw, so figure eloquent must have a way to performing the same.

Comment: Someone is saying sorting a collection with multiple column is possible which is by reversing the order. Maybe you should give it a try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58503520/8607640